# Best Practise and Semantics of namespace nested functions and the use of extern "C"

Tags: c++, portability, abi

I am creating a C++ library with a C-ABI interface.

This is how GCC treats the extern "C" qualifier with regards to mangling:

```
namespace x {

    extern "C" int monkey(int x) {
        return 1;
    }

    int chimpanzee(int x) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The relevant `nm` output:

```
00000000004005cd T _ZN1x10chimpanzeeEi
00000000004005bf T monkey
```

**Question:**
I want to leave functions which are involved in the C-ABI inside a namespace, for maximum flexibility for reuse. **Important Note:** Once the library has been compiled I will give the linker a map file (GCC) or a module definition file (MSVC).

1. Is the mangling output standard behaviour -- will other major compilers (MSVC in specific) strip mangling as well ?
2. are their any pitfalls or best-practises regarding placing functions in a name-space when they are involved in an external ABI?
3. Will this interfere with the C-ABI export of the de-mangled functions during link time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for MSVC.

The namespace itself is not name-mangled, but the name of the namespace is incorporated in to the function's (or object's) name when name mangling occurs.  This process is undocumented, but described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Name_Mangling).

Answering your specific questions by jumping around:

1) There is no Standard-defined behavior regarding name mangling.  What the Standard actually says is that implementations provides a C-compatible linkage for `extern "C"` constructs:

### 7.5.3 [Linkage specifications]

> Every implementation shall provide for
>   linkage to functions written in the C
>   programming language, "C", and linkage
>   to C + + functions, "C++".  [Example:

```
complex sqrt(complex); // C + + linkage by default 
extern "C" { double sqrt(double); // C linkage }
```

> —end example]

Ultimately what this means is that since C has no concept of `namespace`s, if `extern "C"` functions or objects in namespaces, your exported names will lose the namespace qualification.  This leads to...

3) Yes, you can have a linkage problem.  Try this:

### main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_API
#   define MAIN_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

namespace x
{
    extern "C" MAIN_API void foo();
};

namespace y
{
    extern "C" MAIN_API void foo();
};
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAIN_API __declspec(dllexport)
#include "main.h"

void x::foo()
{
    cout << "x::foo()\n";
}

void y::foo()
{
    cout << "y::foo()\n";
}

int main()
{
}
```

This will emit a linker error because the `extern "C"`-ed versions of `x::foo()` and `y::foo()` have lost their namespace identification, so they end up with exactly the same name:  `foo()`

2) Best practices regarding this.  If you must export a C-ABI for functions in namespaces, you have to be careful that the names you end up exporting are not the same.  To some degree, this defeats the purpose of using a `namespace` in the first place.  But you can do something like this:

```
#ifndef MAIN_API
#   define MAIN_API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

namespace x
{
    extern "C" MAIN_API void x_foo();
};

namespace y
{
    extern "C" MAIN_API void y_foo();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad the pitfalls are relatively simple and generally common-sense ones -- perhaps i'll use a c-style prefix on functions that form the C-ABI interface.

Answer (score 5):

What you're doing is fine and will give you the effects that you want. From *The C++ Programming Language, 3rd Edition*, page 208: "A name with C linkage can be declared in a namespace. The namespace will affect the way the name is accessed in  a C++ program, but not the way a linker sees it. The `printf()` from `std` is a typical example. … Even when called with `std::printf()`, it is still the same old C `printf()`."